# Draw array(data structure) with underbraces at subarray

Tags: tables, matrices, arrays

I'm pretty new to latex and I'm having some difficult to draw this:

[image: Ignore the sketch at the top of image]

It is very important that the dots do not be inside a column, but act like a separator (actually it indicates that there are an unknown number of elements between the two parts of array)

I have no idea how to do this. Also if I draw 2 arrays they won't be at same line, and I think it is not the correct way to think to solve the problem...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
 \underbrace{\begin{matrix}%{*{9}{c}}
aa & bb & cc & dd & ee &\parbox{1cm}{\dotfill}& yy & zz
\end{matrix}}_\textrm{text text text}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to underbrace a specific zone in the matrix, you can do it using `pstricks-add`, that has a `psbrace` command. The idea is to define the elements you want to join as `\Rnode`s, then joining these nodes with `\pssbrace`. Unfortunately, the `pdf`option doesn't work here, so hat we have to go the traditional way, latex -> dvi -> ps ->ps2pdf. The parameters used for \psbrace are explained in  § 11 of the documentation.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{matrix}%{*{9}{c}}
aa & \Rnode[ href = -1,vref = -2pt]{B}{bb} & cc & dd & ee &\parbox{1cm}{\dotfill}& \Rnode[ href = 1,vref = -2pt]{Y}{yy} & zz
\end{matrix}
\]
\psset{braceWidth = 0.8pt, braceWidthInner =4pt, braceWidthOuter = 4pt, nodesep =8pt}
\psbrace[rot =90](B)(Y){\clap{Text text text\qquad}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this case the entire array is underbraced. How would I put underbraces only to, lets say, index 2 up to n-2?

Comment: @MasterID: There is a (more complex) solution with `pstricks-add` that uses nodes. See the update to my answer.

Comment: It was exactly what I needed! But it looks much more complex, so I will read with attention. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It' not *that*  complex in its principle. What is complex is the many parameters that are used for the form and the position of the brace. As is usual with pstricks, you have control on almost everything.